# How to change the header format of syslog messages?

Tags: freebsd, syslog

So the syslog log is made up of a header (timestamp + hostname) and a message (tag + content). Is any of this customizable? I mean how can i decide the format of timestamp or whether I want hostname to be logged.

Is there someway to do this from the syslog system call or syslog.conf file?

UPDATE:
I'm using syslogd and FREEBSD8

Comment: That depents on what syslog daemon implementation you're using. Update your question to include that and/or which GNU/Linux distribution (and version) you're using.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty much hardcoded for security reasons (you don't want faked messages which look like they came from host X at time T but came from x at t).

If you want to mess with it, you'd have to hack `usr.sbin/syslogd/syslogd.c`, functions *printline()* and *logmsg()*.

Answer (score 2):

Syslog's date format, limited as it is, is defined in [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424), which FreeBSD's built-in Syslog follows accurately.

If you want more flexibility or detail, you'll either need to post-process your logs, or switch to a different syslog daemon.  Note that by doing so, you may make it impossible for standard log analysis tools to interpret your logs.

One favourite alternative is **[syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/)**, which is available in the ports tree.

```
cd /usr/ports/sysutils/syslog-ng && make install clean
```